# Can't add SilverLight 8 support in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I try to add Windows Phone Silverlight 8 support to Xamarin.Forms Class Library project which created by template `Class Library (Xamarin.Forms) --Visual C#` in Visual Studio 2017. (My solution is created in Visual Studio 2015). But it alerts

`The selected targets require the project to opt-into NuGet 3.0 support`
[image]

How to solve that? I found that NuGet version in VS2017 is 4.0.

Comment: SL and win8 apps are afaik not supported in VS2017 anymore.

Comment: see answer here on how to use msbuild with SL5 SDK instead, could probably do the same with other SDKs if you install them manually - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294628/solution-for-developing-in-windows-silverlight-in-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't add SilverLight 8 support in Visual Studio 2017. How to solve that?

That is because **Silverlight projects are not supported in this version of Visual Studio 2017**. You can take a look: [Visual Studio 2017 Platform Targeting and Compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs).

> **Silverlight**
>
> Silverlight projects are not supported in this version of Visual
> Studio. To maintain Silverlight applications, continue to use Visual
> Studio 2015.
>
> **Windows Store and Windows Phone apps**
>
> Projects for Windows
> Store 8.1 and 8.0, and Windows Phone 8.1 and 8.0 are not supported in
> this release. To maintain these apps, continue to use Visual Studio
> 2015. To maintain Windows Phone 7.x projects, use Visual Studio 2012

So magicandre1981 is right. To resolve this issue, **please continue to use Visual Studio 2015 to maintain Silverlight applications.**

Besides, there is an user voice about support Silverlight projects in Visual Studio 2017: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18610774-support-silverlight-projects-in-visual-studio-2017
. You can follow you comments and vote this voice. Then you can also check the feedback from here.

Hope this can help you.