# Solution for developing in Windows Silverlight in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Our company is trying to remove Visual Studio 2015 all together but we still have some Silverlight code.

Is there a workaround for being able to work with Silverlight in VS 2017 even though it's not supported, or a more light-weight solution **rather than having to keep either both IDE's or just use 2015?**

Comment: I'm left using both IDEs as 2017 wont play nice with it. The solution uses 2017 but if I have to edit SL code I have to go back to the previous IDE version.

Comment: I'm looking to see if anyone is either creating an open source solution or if Microsoft is going to make a plugin or "fix" to support it since Silverlight is still technically supported.

Comment: No and no. also asking for off-site resources are considered off-topic for SO and may lead to this question being closed as off-topic

Comment: I don't believe I'm specifically asking for off-site resources, I'm asking for a solution to developing for Silverlight without having to use an older IDE or two IDE's.

Comment: Update noted. However the answer to your question is that there is no current solution. I've been following this space for a while now. But hey, that is just my opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm left using both IDEs as 2017 does not support it. The solution uses 2017 but if I have to edit SL code I have to go back to the previous IDE version.

To quote [Visual Studio 2017 Platform Targeting and Compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs#compatibility-with-previous-releases)

> **Compatibility with Previous Releases**
>
> **Installation**
>
> You can install and use Visual Studio 2017 alongside previous versions
>   of Visual Studio, including Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013,
>   and Visual Studio 2012.
>
> **Silverlight**
>
> Silverlight projects are not supported in this version of Visual
>   Studio. To maintain Silverlight applications, continue to use Visual
>   Studio 2015.

Comment: "Is there a workaround for being able to work with Silverlight in VS 2017 even though it's not supported, or a more light-weight solution **rather than having to keep either both IDE's or just use 2015?"**

Comment: @obizues clearly Microsoft says no, and you should not bother any more.

Comment: @LexLi this question was asked understanding that Microsoft didn't support this in VS 2017, I'm not sure why you suggest that means there cannot be another solution.

Comment: @obizues it is a closed source application. Do you have some magic while its vendor does not offer that? Stubbornness is useless.

Comment: @obizues There has been countless of "hacks" where a small change to the prerequirements in an ini-file (or something similar) that's part of the installation package for a feature was all that was needed to install the feature.  I'm quite sure it's a purely political decision on MS side, they want to "force" people out of SilverLight, while still not providing anything even close to its features and functionality. So make sure to support initiatives like: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/10027638-create-a-ubiquitous-net-client-application-develo

Comment: @NoOneSpecial, can you link us to one of the "hacks" please? Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

While it is true that Visual Studio 2017 does not support Silverlight5 projects I have found out that MSBuild shipped with Visual Studio 2017 is able to build them if you have [Silverlight5 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28359) installed.

I know that it is not an ideal solution but at least I don't need to keep older Visual Studio installed if I just need to rebuild the SL5 code.

For example I am using following `build.bat` file to build SL5 project with VS2017:

```
@setlocal

@rem Initialize build environment of Visual Studio 2017
call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"
@echo on

@rem Delete output directory
rmdir /S /Q sl5

@rem Clean project
msbuild ..\src\Pkcs11Interop\Pkcs11Interop\Pkcs11Interop.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU /target:Clean || goto :error

@rem Build project
msbuild ..\src\Pkcs11Interop\Pkcs11Interop\Pkcs11Interop.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU /target:Build || goto :error

@rem Copy result to output directory
mkdir sl5 || goto :error
copy ..\src\Pkcs11Interop\Pkcs11Interop\bin\Release\Pkcs11Interop.dll sl5 || goto :error
copy ..\src\Pkcs11Interop\Pkcs11Interop\bin\Release\Pkcs11Interop.xml sl5 || goto :error

@echo *** BUILD SL5 SUCCESSFUL ***
@endlocal
@exit /b 0

:error
@echo *** BUILD SL5 FAILED ***
@endlocal
@exit /b 1
```

Comment: If only somebody proficient with visual studio extensions would write an extension to load silverlight projects and run sort of this script in the build process.

Comment: @Alex I created a Visual Studio extension for Silverlight. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54858120/90287.

Answer (score 7):

The [Silverlight for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RamiAbughazaleh.SilverlightProjectSystem) extension on the Visual Studio Marketplace unofficially supports Silverlight projects in Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019.

It's FREE.

Disclosure:
I published the Visual Studio extension.

Comment: This worked for me after finding a copy of the Silverlight Developer Runtime (x64 version) to download here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=57768